# Break statement not exiting for loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a for loop so that when there is an item for sale and an item wanted with a lower price, it removes the two listings and exits the for loop using 'j'. For some reason though, the value of askingPrice is staying the same, and removing all items with a lower price, instead of just removing the first one it encounters, and breaking the loop. Is there a different way I should be exiting the loop, or do I just have a logic error somewhere?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++){
    if(itemArray[i].status == "for sale"){
        int askingPrice = itemArray[i].price;
        string ITEM = itemArray[i].type;
        for(int j = 0; j < elements; j++){
            SOLD = 0;
            position = 0;
            if(itemArray[j].status == "wanted" && itemArray[j].type == ITEM && itemArray[j].price >= askingPrice){
                soldArray[soldPosition].type = itemArray[j].type;
                soldArray[soldPosition].price = askingPrice;
                soldPosition += 1;
                //cout << soldPosition << endl;
                if(i > j){
                for(int k = i; k < elements; k++){
                    itemArray[k].price = itemArray[k+1].price;
                    itemArray[k].type = itemArray[k+1].type;
                    itemArray[k].status = itemArray[k+1].status;
                    if(k == elements - 2){
                        elements = elements - 1;
                    }
                }
                position = 1;
                }
                for(int k = j; k < elements; k++){
                    if(k == elements - 1){
                        elements = elements - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    itemArray[k].price = itemArray[k+1].price;
                    itemArray[k].type = itemArray[k+1].type;
                    itemArray[k].status = itemArray[k+1].status;
                }
                if(position = 0){
                for(int k = i; k < elements; k++){
                    if(k == elements - 1){
                        elements = elements - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    itemArray[k].price = itemArray[k+1].price;
                    itemArray[k].type = itemArray[k+1].type;
                    itemArray[k].status = itemArray[k+1].status;
                }
                }
                SOLD = 1;
            }
            if(SOLD == 1){
                i = i-2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a break statement exits only the innermost for loop, while loop, or switch - it has no way to exit more than one scope - how would it know how many levels to exit?.

Comment: I'm only trying to break out of one loop though. It's the break statement at the bottom, and I want it to break out of the for(j = 0...) loop.

Comment: Why don't you try simplifying your code for posting, and give the words some breathing space?

Comment: I won't say this is correct, but to break out of the for-loop, the placement of the break needs to be just before the closing for-loop brace.  Use your editor's highlighting of paired braces to find it, if you need to.  Think about other ways to exit a loop, such as loop-continuation conditions, including compound conditions.

Comment: The next end brace after the if statement with the "break" in it is the end of the for loop I'm trying to exit. I played around with putting it in different places, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Your `break` is positioned to break out of the `for(int j = 0; j < elements; j++)` loop. If that's the one you wanted, then maybe your problem is something preventing the break line from being hit, such as `SOLD` not being set. You should probably debug through your code and see if things are happening differently than you intended.

Comment: @AdrianM. - that is not correct. A `break` statement can occur anywhere in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  I didn't mean that the language or compiler requires it, or that it's stylistically / by convention correct; I was trying to guide him to place it in a way that he could be more confident of which loop of would actually exit.

Answer (score 1):

`break` only breaks out of the innermost loop.  There are 2 ways you can conquer this problem:

1. Set a flag and break out of each subsequent loop if it is triggered.
2. Extract functions from your program and distinguish single loop breaks from total loop breaks using `return` to break form multiple associated loops vs `break` for a single loop.  For larger problems always use this method, it will make your code easier to read, well structured and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a sentinel value and sequentially break out of each loop. (The modern way of doing things) OR Cause a massive wave of "You're doing it wrong!" screaming and just use a goto statement. I advocate goto only if you are nesting for loops on 4th or 5th order or higher. If that's the case: "YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG!"

Comment: I'd have to see it, but that five deep `goto` could be a great readability enhancer. Might be harder to convince me you really did need to go five deep. Or that you couldn't just pack it into a function and `return`.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason though, the value of askingPrice is staying the same

You are not changing *askingPrice* anywhere in your code.

> when there is an item for sale and an item wanted

An `itemArray` object **cannot** have both status `"for sale"` and `"wanted"` at the same time.

So lets say `if(itemArray[i].status == "for sale")` is *true* in `i` loop. The control goes into the `if` statement and initializes `askingPrice` and `ITEM` with *ith* item's `price` and `type`.

From there, `j` loop is started from **0th element** in *`itemArray`*. Your `j` loop has no regard for `status = "for sale"`, this loop only knows the *price* and *type*. At this point `SOLD = 0;`

Now control checks this

```
if(itemArray[j].status == "wanted" && itemArray[j].type == ITEM && itemArray[j].price >= askingPrice)
```

Please Note that above `if` can either be true or false. But in any case it is not considering

`status = "for sale";` Therefore, when the above `if` condition is true, it runs the code within and deletes low priced item according to the condition and when it is false, the code never reaches `SOLD = 1;` which does not allow `j` loop to break as `if(SOLD == 1) break;`

So there you have it and yes you are right, it is indeed a logical error.